# При загрузке библиотеки выдает ошибку (telebot)

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot, qrcode

создаю телеграм бота на питоне, который может переводить полученный текст в QR code и присылать его пользователю, но при запуске, используя библиотеки telebot и pyqrcode (или qrcode), выдает ошибку "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyqrcode'". Если создать другой питон файл используя только библу pyqrcode (или qrcode), то все работает. Пожалуйста помогите.

```
import telebot
import pyqrcode
import time

token="some_token"
bot=telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(msg):
    bot.send_chat_action(msg.chat.id, 'typing')
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id,'Hey There,\n Use /qr_code to generate QR CODE ')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['qr_code'])
def qr_code_handler(message):
    bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'typing')
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Send Text or Url")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, qrcode)

def qrcode(message):
    url=pyqrcode.create(message.text)
    url.png('qrcode.png',scale=15)
    bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'upload_document')
    bot.send_document(message.chat.id,open('qrcode.png','rb' ))


while True:
    try:
        bot.infinity_polling(True)
    except Exception:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Рандомный код взятый с github на котором у меня такая же ошибка

Comment: pip install pyqrcode

Answer (score 0):

1. Возможно у вас включено виртуальное окружение.
2. Вы неправильно назвали файл с вашей программой
3. Вы забыли установить pyqrcode

Вы пользуетесь редактором кода или IDE наподобие PyCharm?